# Using the Comparable interface to sort through dates

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a simple program that will sort the order of given dates, by sorting from earliest date to latest.

I'm able to sort the dates by their years, however when 2 dates have the same year and I need to sort by month, it starts having problems. I've been trying to nest if-statements and tried implementing while loops but I can't quite seem to get it right. I know that in my if statements, I'm missing some kind of statement that tells java to sort by `month < other.month` and `day < other.day` but I can't quite get it right...

Input/Output currently:

> [10/5 1999, 19/5 1999, 10/3 1999, 19/3 1999, 10/5 2000, 19/5 2000, 10/3 2000, 19/3 2000]
>
> [10/3 1999, 10/3 2000, 19/3 1999, 10/5 1999, 10/5 2000, 19/5 1999, 19/3 2000, 19/5 2000]

```
class Date implements Comparable<Date> {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public Date(int year, int month, int day) {
        this.year = year;
        this.month = month;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Date other) {
        if(year < other.year) {
            return Integer.compare(this.year, other.year);
        }
        if(year == other.year) {
            return Integer.compare(this.month, other.month);
        }
        if(month == other.month) {
            return Integer.compare(this.day, other.day);
        }
        return day;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return day + "/" + month + " " + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first condition should be `if(year != other.year) {`

Comment: `dates.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Date::getYear)
                    .thenComparingInt(Date::getMonth));`

Comment: I hope you knew already, so just for anyone else reading this question some time in the future: For production code you should not develop your own date class. You should use the built-in `LocalDate` (and yes, it implements `Comparable`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking all cases for years, `year < other.year` should be `year != other.year` In addition to that there's some other issues. What you want to be doing is:

```
if years aren't same
 return sort by year
else, if months aren't same
 return sort by months
else
 return sort by days
```

Answer (score 2):

Coding comparison for three fields is error-prone. To minimize the risk of bugs use the `comparingInt` and `thenComparingInt` methods of the `Comparator` interface, like Aomine already mentioned in a comment:

```
private static final Comparator<Date> dateComparator 
        = Comparator.comparingInt((Date d) -> d.year)
                .thenComparingInt(d -> d.month)
                .thenComparingInt(d -> d.day);

@Override
public int compareTo(Date other) {
    return dateComparator.compare(this, other);
}
```

Even better, provide getters for the fields and use `Date::getYear` instead of `(Date d) -> d.year` and similarly for month and day.

The advantage is not so much that it’s shorter. The greatest advantage is it’s pretty hard to get wrong.